# image not uploaded in the folder what we given

Tags: cakephp

### **Controller/imagesController.php**

```
<?php 
class ImagesController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    var $uses=array('Images');

    public function index(){

    //  $this->set('posts', $this->carrier->find('all'));
        if($this->request->is('post')){
             Configure::read();
             pr($this->data); 
            $this->Images->create();
            $filename = null;


if (
    !empty($this->request->data['Images']['fname']['tmp_name'])
    && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Images']['fname']['tmp_name'])
) {
    // Strip path information
    $filename = basename($this->request->data['Images']['fname']['name']); 
    pr($filename);
    move_uploaded_file( $this->data['Images']['fname']['name'],WWW_ROOT . DS . 'UserImages' . DS . $filename  );

//$this->data['Images']['fname'] = $filename;
}

pr($filename);
// Set the file-name only to save in the database
//pf_($fiename);
$this->request->data['Images']['fname'] = $filename;
$uid = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->request->data['Images']['uid'] = $uid;
//pf_($this->request->data);
if ($this->Images->save($this->request->data)) {
  pr($this->request->data);
   // ...
     /*if ($this->Carrier->save($this->request->data)) {
                 if ($this->Carrier->save($this->data)) {
                 */
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Details has been saved.'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'images','action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Details'));
            }
            }
        }



public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'index') {
        return true;
    }




    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
}
?>
```

---

### **View/Images/index.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Images', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Images.fname', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file'));?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Apply');?>
```

Here code for file upload are shows sucussful and file name are inserterd in db but the original image not uploaded in **UserImages** folder ..
for this checked but i did n't find solution please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->data['Images']['fname']['name']` only contains the filename.
`$this->data['Images']['fname']['tmp_name']` contains the file data and should be used with `move_uploaded_file()`;

So you should change

```
move_uploaded_file($this->data['Images']['fname']['name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'UserImages'.DS.$filename)
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($this->data['Images']['fname']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'UserImages'.DS.$filename)
```

You could also do a check on `move_uploaded_file()`

```
if(move_uploaded_file($this->data['Images']['fname']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT.DS.'UserImages'.DS.$filename)) {
    //continue
} else {
    //show error
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It always a bad practice to use move_uploaded_file() in cakephp...because cakephp always provide an ImageBehavior for image uploading ...That take care for your image, folder & image validations also....
If you don't know about image behavior you can learn it from here .....
http://cakephplogics.blogspot.in/2014/07/cakephp-image-upload-behavior.html

Comment: please let me know for whatis negative in this question